# How to get the dependent tables in DB2

Tags: database, db2

I have a table "Account". I want to get all the dependent table of Account. How can i get the name of dependent tables in DB2 ?

Comment: What platform is DB2 running on and what version is it? Different platforms/versions can have very different methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [GET_DEPENDENCY](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0055165.html)  procedure.  per documentation

```
The GET_DEPENDENCY procedure provides the capability to list all 
objects that are dependent upon the given object.
```

You need to call it like

```
CALL DBMS_UTILITY.GET_DEPENDENCY('TABLE', 'SCHEMA1', 'T1')@
```